# Task Queue REST API - invalid value error - payload base64 encoding

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, task-queue

Using the GAE Task Queue REST API, I am calling Tasks `insert` and sometimes get back an error 400 with message "Invalid Value". Other times the insert is successful. I believe the error is related to the base64 encoding of the payload.

Specifically, it seems that any encoded payload that contains the special "/" character is rejected. Does anyone know what flavor of base64 encoding is expected as input here? My client program is a Google Apps Script using its `Utilities.base46Encode` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting "/" to "_" did it:

```
function base64Encode(str, opts){
  return Utilities.base64Encode(str, opts).replace(/\//g,'_');
}
```

Comment: Just ran into the same problem. Sounds like it might be Base64Url. Did `+` need to become `-` as well?